# Difference between categories,subclasses and notifications,delegations

Tags: objective-c

I am confusing from these areas.I searched on net.But every site giving different solutions.And i am new for this technology.So please provide corrects differences and definitions for this list.

Comment: You should read a good book rather than trying to write some code straight away. Trial and error is good for some things but when you are totally new to something it is best to learn the conventions first.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Categories vs. Subclasses

Categories let you expand the API of *existing classes* without changing their type. Subclassing also expands the API but introduces a new type. Additionally, subclassing lets you add state.

### Notifications vs. Delegation

Notifications are a way to let unrelated classes communicate. Delegation on the other hand lets related classes communicate using a more explicitly defined interface.

Comment: Additionally subclassing lets you add state. can explain this in detail

Comment: @RameshMuthe Instances of classes have state in the form of properties and ivars. An example would be a view's `backgroundColor` or `frame`. Subclassing let's you add ivars to carry more state. Categories can't add ivars.

Answer (score 7):

**Categories :**  Categories provide the ability to add functionality to an object without subclassing or changing the actual object. A handy tool, they are often used to add methods to existing classes, such as NSString or your own custom objects.

*`Know more for category from here :`* [categories in objective-c](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)

**Subclasses :** Every object you create in your Cocoa application descends from the 'NSObject' foundation class.  The NSObject class identifies properties and methods which apply to all objects.  The NSObject class is divided into smaller groups of objects, called subclasses.  Objects in these subclasses not only conform to the protocol of NSObject, they are also defined more precisely by the methods that govern their subclass.  Every object class inherits from the superclasses above it in the object hierarchy, and also declares the methods which make it a unique class.

*`Know more for subclasses from here :`* [Suclassing & SuperClassing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Subclasses_and_superclasses)

**Notifications :** A notification is a message sent to one or more observing objects to inform them of an event in a program. The notification mechanism of Cocoa follows a broadcast model. It is a way for an object that initiates or handles a program event to communicate with any number of objects that want to know about that event. These recipients of the notification, known as observers, can adjust their own appearance, behavior, and state in response to the event. The object sending (or posting) the notification doesn’t have to know what those observers are. Notification is thus a powerful mechanism for attaining coordination and cohesion in a program. It reduces the need for strong dependencies between objects in a program (such dependencies would reduce the reusability of those objects). Many classes of the Foundation, AppKit, and other Objective-C frameworks define notifications that your program can register to observe.

*`Know more for notifications from here :`* [NSNotification Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Delegates :** A delegate is an object that acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object when that object encounters an event in a program. The delegating object is often a responder object—that is, an object inheriting from NSResponder in AppKit or UIResponder in UIKit—that is responding to a user event. The delegate is an object that is delegated control of the user interface for that event, or is at least asked to interpret the event in an application-specific manner. So basically Basically, delegation is a way of allowing objects to interact with each other without creating strong interdependencies between them, since this makes the design of your application less flexible. Instead of objects controlling one another, they can have a delegate which they send (or delegate) messages to, and the delegate does whatever they do, in order to respond and act to this message, and then usually return something back to the other object.

*`Know more for delegates from here :`* [Application Delegate Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)