# Why would you use categories over subclasses?

Tags: objective-c, subclassing, objective-c-category

I just try to figure out the upside of categories compared to subclassing... I do understand how they are implemented, but the only upside I see right at the moment is, that it saves you from refactoring your whole code, if you wanna extend a used class in a later stage, which normaly shouldn't happen with a good planning. Otherwise it takes about the same time to implement as a subclass and it doesn't really bring different functionality. So for my knowledge about subclasses vs. categories I don't see a reason why to use categories. Can someone please wash my head and explain the reason for the existence of categories? I'd be very thankful :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between categories,subclasses and notifications,delegations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563907/difference-between-categories-subclasses-and-notifications-delegations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're focusing on objects that you create, in which case, subclassing is fine. But what if you're calling some Cocoa method that returns some standard object. Do you want to have to create a new instance of your subclass everytime just so you can use your new method? No, it's much more convenient to be able to create methods that you add to existing class via category.

Also, you might want your new methods to be available to not only the base class, but all of its subclasses, too (e.g. if you add extension to `NSString`, it's available to `NSMutableString` instances, too).

For more information, see the discussion in [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) in the *Programming with Objective-C* guide.

Comment: I think this might have flipped the switch in my brain :) Both of your arguments do show clearly advantages compared to subclassing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A major difference is that categories can not add instance variables, subclasses can.

Additionally there are classes that are very difficult to subclass such as `NSString`, see the subclassing notes. Here is an excerpt: "It is **possible** to subclass NSString (and NSMutableString), **but** doing so requires providing storage facilities for the string (which is not inherited by subclasses) and implementing two primitive methods." As soon as you see **but** you know it will not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new method to the NSString class. Try doing it by subclassing NSString and by adding a category. One of these takes two minutes, the other you are never going to get working properly. That will then answer your question.